# Can't save file with non-ASCII symbols in file name via Django models

Tags: python, django, utf-8, locale

I have this problem only on production server. When I'm trying to upload file with named with Russian symbols, I'm getting an error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position...
```

Saving:

```
#... code above ...
file = request.FILES.get('file')

try:
    item = ModelItem(
        model=file,
        title=file.name,
    )

    item.save()
# ... code below ...
```

Full traceback:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 589, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 617, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 698, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 731, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 921, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 919, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 877, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 301, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 89, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 50, in save
    name = self.get_available_name(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 75, in get_available_name
    while self.exists(name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 265, in exists
    return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 18, in exists
    os.stat(path)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 31-34: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to set

```
os.environ['LANG'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'
```

when server starts with, also I checked out output of

```sh
locale -a
```

and found all needed locales, but it didn't help.

Comment: please add your code for the upload ... as well as the top of the traceback

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I've added code. Is it what you asked?

Comment: and please add your ModelItem class

Comment: @JoranBeasley, it's just a regular model, file field is model = models.FileField(upload_to="user_uploads")

I think there is a trouble with locales in gunicorn, or somewhere else.

Comment: try `print repr(file.name)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley, it prints u'\u0442\u0435\u0441\u0442.png'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79572/discussion-between-vladimir-solovyov-and-joran-beasley).